# Why is the tubing diameter for a cold plate different on input and output?

Tags: kegging, tubing, serving

I'm making a parts list to make a jockey box out of a spare cooler.  I noticed that both Northern Brewer and Micromatic recommend different tubing sizes for the input to the cold plate and the output from it.

https://www.northernbrewer.com/cold-plate-fitting-out

vs

https://www.northernbrewer.com/cold-plate-fitting-in

Why don't the cold plates use the typical 3/16" beverage tubing on both sides?

Comment: My answer is for long line best practices. I have a couple chill plates that have the same size in and out. If you notice they both use the same Washer. They are just giving you recommended fittings for proper use.

Answer (score 1):

They step down in size to **help prevent** overcarbonation at the end of the line. For when a keg is on a jockey box for several hours at above normal pressures.

Beer flows easier and with less pushing pressure the larger the line is. The more  diameter step downs to the final diameter at the tap the better.

This is why you will see many jockey boxes start at 1/2 or 9/16 out of the sankey keg.

But I would still recommend using beer gas, if you think a single keg would take more than 4 hours to kick. Or you will just blow foam towards the end from overcarbonation.